# How to find all points directly next to a point?

Tags: algorithm, coordinates, distance

I have a set of coordinates. I am looking for a way to get all surrounding neighbours for a given coordinate. I am looking for all the points that are directly next to it, such that you do not need to "travel" through another point to get there.

I originally tried this with just K-nearest neighbours, but it gives every closest point, even it is not directly next to you

An example:

If I have a grid of coordinate like such:

```
A
                      E
             C   D
      B
      F
```

I want a result such that if you are A you would return B. I can't go to C or F, as B is in the way

At B you return A, C and F

At C you return B and D

At D you return C and E

At E you return D

Is there a name of an algorithm that acts like this? Or some kind of method I can use?

Comment: You would require something known as 'Adjacency matrix' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix and this how it's represented via code https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations/

Comment: thats perfect, thank you

Comment: Why do you need to pass though `B` when you're in `A` and want to go to `C` ?

Comment: At B you return A, C and F, why?

Answer (score 0):

First get the max coordinate position, say (3,4) assuming it is 0 indexing, then create a 2d matrix (grid) of size max+1, in our case (4,5), and fill in your coordinates.

To get the neighbours of a particular coordinate, travel in all 4 directions and fetch the first neighbour you find in each direction.

Note: Dont forget to initialise your 2d matrix with a default value, it will help you in finding neighbours.